# How to run a schema proc from another schema

Tags: sql-server, database-schema

Let's say that in a multi-schema db we have these 2 procs:

```
Create proc S1004.proc1 
As
  Exec proc2
GO
Create proc S1004.proc2 
As
   Select 1
```

Then, when I try to run **proc1** from **sa** login, sql issues an error : Could not find stored procedure 'proc2'.

I know that if we add **schema** to proc2 in the body of proc1, then it can resolve the schema.

Is there any other solution for this problem.

Comment: Ok, you answered your own question... or?

Comment: @OzrenTkalcecKrznaric, I can't do that , I just simplified my problem here. Suppose that we have another proc that can call different procs like proc1 generically. we can't go to any single proc and attach the schema as we have multiple schemas for each proc as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use your schema in the 'scope' of user (be aware that users and schemas are separated in SQL Server), you could get away with this:

```
CREATE USER S1004 FOR LOGIN S1004 WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = S1004;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE S1004.proc1 
WITH EXECUTE AS 'S1004'
AS
  EXECUTE proc2
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE S1004.proc2 
AS
   SELECT 1

EXEC S1004.proc1
```

What happens here is that you create user S1004 with a default schema with the same name. That schema will be searched for object when object is not found immediately in the scope of current schema.

When you need to resolve your schema in a procedure, you run the procedure in the context of that user (see `WITH EXECUTE AS 'S1004'`) and schema resolution will succeed.

However, pay attention that this changes execution scope to the another user. It's a workaround, but under the circumstances it's the best you can get.

Comment: Thanks. sounds to be the answer. can you please explain the last line a little more? so for us, a schema proc can only be run under sa or any user whose default schema is set to the proc's schema. does this cause the problem you mentioned there? I doubt it does.

Comment: The way you put it, I believe it doesn't. Or, it doesn't as long as you can control/administer privileges of any user you create.